# Fourier series of half of $\sin(\pi x)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

So my question is: 
Find the Fourier series (using integrals) for the half wave rectified sine function:
$$f(x)= \begin{cases}0&-1<x<0\\
       \sin(\pi x)&   0<x<1\end{cases}$$
where f(x) has period 2.

How am I meant to answer this? As I get the answers $a_0=0$,
$b_n=0$, except at $n=1$, and
$a_n= [1+(-1)^{2m+1}]/[-4m\pi(m+1)]$    where $n=2m+1$

Have I made a  mistake? Because i really don't know what I'm doing aha...

Comment: Attempted to edit, but may have gotten some parts wrong, specifically in $a_n=...$

Comment: Could you show us how you computed the $a_i$ and $b_i$?  Since $a_0 = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} f(x) \; dx$, you should not get $a_0 = 0$.

Comment: I posted an answer, but I'm deleting it because I assumed you were using the complex exponential form of the Fourier series. But, reading more carefully, I see you referring to $a_n$ and $b_n$, which suggests that you are using the form involving sines and cosines. It would be helpful if you would edit to show the form of the Fourier series you are using, along with the integral which defines the coefficients. There are several conventions in use, depending on which author/book you read.